# what is the max size of TextProperty on google app engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, max

```
class JsTree_JsonData(db.Model):
    JsonData=db.TextProperty()
```

i can;t find what is the TextProperty

did you know  ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[1 megabyte](https://web.archive.org/web/20120101050516/http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits).

The archived page lists maximum entity size as 1 megabyte.